# Calling one MXML from AS code

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I am creating an AIR application, The mainapp.mxml has a button and VBOX. When clicked on button, child.mxml should be displayed in VBOX.

Would appreciate if the code is in flex also , as it would be easy for me to modify the tags.

can anyone help me how to do it please! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click handler to the button, in that handler create an instance of child and add it to the VBox:

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" label="My Button" click="myButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

And the handler:

```
function myButton_clickHandler(event:Event):void {
  var child:Child = new Child();
  myVBox.addChild(child);
}
```

Comment: It works thanks. But one small warning when I execute the code            ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildIndex()
 at mx.managers::SystemManager/getChildIndex()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1665]
 at mx.managers.systemClasses::ActiveWindowManager/mouseDownHandler()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\systemClasses\ActiveWindowManager.as:471]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex 4, you could also use `states` to handle this.  The button would simply change the state, and the VBox would be included in whichever state you're setting:

```
<fx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
    private function changeState():void {
        currentState = (currentState == "default") ? "showVBox" : "default";
    }
 ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
  <s:State name="default"  />
  <s:State name="showVBox" />
</s:states>

<mx:VBox id="myVBox" includeIn="showVBox" />
<mx:Button label="Show/Hide VBox" click="changeState()" />
```

In my example, clicking the button simply swaps the state between "default" and "showVBox".  This allows the player to add/remove the VBox for you, rather than worrying about doing it yourself.

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tested the above code, so the namespaces could be off :)